# SQL query to list all the colleges that have at least one student ranking between 1 & 3 for the year 2020

Tags: mysql, sql, database

- In a drone championship every year, students from different colleges
  participate and win rankings. Given the table structure in the image
  below,
- *Please write a SQL query to list all the colleges that have at least one student ranking between 1 & 3 for the year 2020*.
- **Expected Output: College Name, Rank of their best student rank in 2020, number of students who had ranking b/w 1 and 3 in 2020**

  ```
   Colleges Table (ID int, name varchar(50)) 

   Students Table (ID int, name varchar(30), collegeld int)

   Rankings Table (studentID, ranking, year)
  ```

---

I have tried but not getting it properly,
please help...

```
SELECT 
    Colleges.Name,  
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Rankings.ranking DESC)   as "Best Ranking",
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Colleges.ID ORDER BY Rankings.ranking) as "Total Students in Ranking"
from
    Colleges
    JOIN Students on Students.collegeID = Colleges.ID
    JOIN Rankings on Students.ID = Rankings.studentID
where
    Rankings.year = 2020
    and Rankings.ranking >= 3;
```

Comment: tag your database , which dbms are you using? also provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly , this is what you need to do:

> list all the colleges that have at least one student ranking between 1 & 3 for the year 2020.

```
select * from colleges c
where exists ( select 1 from students s
                join Rankings r on s.ID = r.studentID 
                and s.collegeID = c.ID 
                and r.ranking <= 3
                and r.year = 2020
)
```

to answer your new question:

> College Name, Rank of their best student rank in 2020, number of students who had ranking b/w 1 and 3 in 2020

```
select 
    c.Name   
    , min(ranking) 
    , count(*)
from colleges c
join students s 
   on s.collegeID = c.ID 
join Rankings r 
   on s.ID = r.studentID 
   and r.ranking <= 3
   and r.year = 2020
group by c.Name
```

Comment: @AkashNikam . . . This information belongs in the *question* not in a comment.  This answers the question that you asked, and I would suggest that you accept this answer.

Comment: @eshirvana &@gordonlinoff, I have updated my Question, please have a look over it.

Comment: @AkashNikam , you are asking a new question , see updated answer